# C# - Entity Framework updating relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using C# with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework to create a RESTful API.
Everything is running fine, however there is one case that I am trying to solve.

Say I have those 3 classes below.

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Option
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CarOption
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Car { get; set; }
    public int Option { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when I try to update CarOption, the Entity Framework will update the related objects too.
I was expecting only the relationship would be updated. Meaning, the framework would discard the other values of *Option* object and use only the Primary Key to update *CarOption* table.

For example:
Assuming that the following code is an example of JSON generate by the API.

```
{
    "id":1
    "Car":{
        "id":1,
        "year":2020
    },
    "option":{
        "id":1,
        "label":"gear"
    },
    "value":"manual"
}
```

If I change the payload and update the option part as

```
{
...
    "option":{
        "id":1,
        "label":"gear2"
    },
...
}
```

, the Entity Framework will update the table **Option** with the new value even though the attribute `id` is present which means that object already exists.
I am using `DbContext.CarOption.Update(*payload*)`.

Is there any solution to avoid this behavior?

Comment: If you do a `.Find` first it'll start tracking the changes, then modify each field `carOption.Value = 123` then `.SaveChanges`. By doing `.Update` it will treat the whole object as changed instead of the select items you actually want to change and that's when you lose data

Comment: Can you include the code that you have to convert the JSON into the `CarOption` model? As well as the entire code that you have for the DbContext interaction? Based off of what you've shown, those results don't really make sense

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I was wondering if there was another way to do it. But it makes sense. I will implement my project in the way you said.